# joomla css changes not seen

Tags: css, joomla

I was trying to modify the css of joomla solarsentinel template. But my changes (some of them) are not seen at all!

The site is labmond.sism.org, my css is embedded in the header. here's the code

```
// Formattazione Introduzione
div.bodycontent {
    font-family: 'book antiqua', palatino;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    background: url('".$this->baseurl."/templates/".$this->template."/images/labmond-bkg.jpg') no-repeat center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}

div.full-article h3 {
    color: #ff0000;
}

div.full-article h5 {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;i
}

.csscolumns section.paragrafo {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 50px;
    -moz-column-rule: solid #DBDBDB 1px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 50px;
    -webkit-column-rule: solid #DBDBDB 1px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 50px;
    column-rule: solid #DBDBDB 1px;
}

div.full-article section.paragrafo{
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}

// Tabella iscritti
table.iscrizioni{width: 100%; border-collapse:collapse;}
table.iscrizioni tr.head td, table.iscrizioni tr.data td{ border: 2px solid}
table.iscrizioni tr.number td{font-weight:bold; color: blue}";
```

I don't understand why it gets overridden! If I inspect div.bodycontent I don't even see my style as inherited or overridden!

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `// Formattazione Introduzione` with `/* Formattazione Introduzione */`

That is not a properly formed comment and all of the style declarations after that will not work.

Comment: It's an easy mistake to miss. I didn't notice it until I copied the entire source of the page in to my editor.